# Following a Twitter Authorization Dialogue with an Alert in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, twitter, alert

I am using the iOS5 Twitter API to get a user's permission to use their Twitter account. This pops open a dialogue from which they can choose to Give or Decline permission to the application. I would like to be able to open an alert if the user accepts but doesn't have a Twitter account set up on their iPhone, however as there is already a dialogue open, opening an alert at this point fails. How can I add an alert immediately after the Twitter permissions dialogue is dismissed?

```
- (IBAction)logInToTwitter:(id)sender
{
    //  First, we need to obtain the account instance for the user's Twitter account
    ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType 
                     withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
      if (granted) 
      {
        NSArray *twitterAccounts = [[store accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType] autorelease];

        if ([twitterAccounts count] > 0) 
        {
           //All good
        }
        else
        {
           //Open Alert
        }

      }
   }];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "opening an alert at this point fails". Is the app crashing? Or is there simply no alert? If the app is not crashing and you can not see the alert, are you sure that the alert is not there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does cause an error when showing the alert view.  The way to make this work is to create a separate function.

```
- (void)noTwitterAccountMessage {
    UIAlertView *alertViewTwitter = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Twitter Accounts"
                                                           message:@"There are no Twitter accounts configured. You can add or create a Twitter account in Settings."
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertViewTwitter show];
}
```

and then inside the account store callback, you should call it like this

```
-(void)requestTwitterAccess
{
    [self.accStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:self.twitterType
                     withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                         if (!granted) {
                             [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(noTwitterAccountMessage) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
                         }
}];
```

}